# How to use PHP rexep or preg_match to extract letters and numbers from a string

Tags: php, regex

Working with a ficticuous string such as;

```
$string = 'Ford : LTD 1988 Ford Station Wagon with HP 351 H Engine and Performance Transmission';
```

How could I use rexexp or preg_match (I don't know which would be better either) to extract a sequence of letters and numbers ("HP 351 H") from that string to use in another variable (ie: $EngineSize)

The above is a fictious example, I'm just trying to make it clear that I'm trying to extract letters and numbers from a UI.

NOTE: Being that this is coming from a UI, the engine size may be positioned anywhere in the string and the format may be with or without spaces and may or may not have a letter at the end, as well as the model could be 2 or 3 letters (ie; LE, LT, LTD etc) as well as the engine size could be 2 - 3 digits possibly  followed by 2 or three letters).

If anyone wouldn't mind showing me how to write an expression to retrieve this data and explain to me which is better (regexp or preg_match) I'd be most appreciative and I thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to explain to _yourself_ why `LTD 1988` in this example should not be extracted, but `HP 351 H` should - and you've already done half of the whole work.

Comment: I don't understand the point you're trying to make. So what if I don't want LTD 1988?? It's just a fictious example and Im just trying to get one aspect of a horses color

Comment: If anyone wouldn't mind posting a  helpful answer I'd be most appreciative

Comment: `LTD 1988` is a sequence of capital letters followed by a sequence of digits - the same as `HP 351`. How exactly a program should understand the difference between these sequences?

Comment: Sorry I used caps, For all I know it could be LtD or LTD lTD or... (You get the idea)
I've been working on drawing it out on paper, I just don't know whether to use rexexp or preg_match but I could narrow the "Query" down to 2 or 3 letters grouped, followed by 2 or 3 numbers with a possible space between, possibly followed by another letter (or2). I just don't know how to write it in code and use it in another variable (ie: $EngSize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex matches exactly what you describe, but there is a good chance of false positives:

```
/(?<=\s|^)[a-zA-Z]{2,3} ?\d\d\d? ?[a-zA-Z]{1,3}?(?=\s|$)/
```

Comment: Thank you @Borre for your help but I'm still at a loss about whether to use rexexp or preg_match and how I would store this info in a variable for later use. I'm sorry raina77ow, I don't understand the use of var_dump. If you wouldn't mind elaborating on that I'd be most appreciative

Comment: Also, What is /(?<=\s before the | (or) operator? I'm asking becasue from what I've learned, ^ is the start of a reg exp

Comment: ?<= means positive lookbehind, which means it checks whether there is either a whitespace or the start of the string, but it does not add it to the match. You can remove ?<=, but then you might get whitespace in the matched string.

Comment: preg_match uses regular expressions, so the answer is use both, approximately like so:
$matches;
$input='Ford : LTD 1988 Ford Station Wagon with HP 351 H Engine and Performance Transmission'
preg_match('/(?<=\s|^)[a-zA-Z]{2,3} ?\d\d\d? ?[a-zA-Z]{1,3}?(?=\s|$)/', $input, $matches);
//Matches are now in $matches

Comment: Hi again @Borre, Sorry for  my delay in responding. I pretty much got all that... I'm having trouble with checking multiple variables with one preg_match(). Lemme explain: I have a feed I am reading from which it returns 1 - infinite numbers of results (Cars for sale in USA) and within the "title" of each I am trying to just extract the engine size and model (LE, LT etc) from each but I am getting undefined offset errors